# How to use 'ng-virtual-keyboard' in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to integrate **ng-virtual-keyboard** in my Angular6 project. But it's not working!!!

Steps I do -

1. `npm install ng-virtual-keyboard`
2. `npm install --save @types/virtual-keyboard` (this command mentioned in 'TypeScript' section of 'https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard')
3. Add `angular.min.js` and `jquery.min.js` script in Head tag of the index page.

index.html -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  ...
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

4. Include `ng-virtual-keyboard` in app.module.ts (**getting error - Cannot find module 'ng-virtual-keyboard'**)

app.module.ts -

```
...
import { NgVirtualKeyboardModule } from 'ng-virtual-keyboard';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgVirtualKeyboardModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

5. app.component.html -

   `<input type='text' ng-model="yourModel" ng-virtual-keyboard/>`
6. app.component.ts -

   `import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

   `@Component({...})`

   `export class AppComponent { }`
7. angular.json -

   `"scripts": ["./node_modules/ng-virtual-keyboard/dist/ng-virtual-keyboard.js"]`
8. **After clicking in the input box, nothing is happening.**

package.json -

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.10",
        "@angular/core": "^6.1.10",
        ...
        "@types/virtual-keyboard": "^1.26.1",
        "ng-virtual-keyboard": "^0.4.0",
        "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
        "tslib": "^2.0.0",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.28"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.12.2",
        "@angular/cli": "^7.2.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.10",
        ...
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "^2.9.2"
    }
}
```

Reference URLs:-

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-virtual-keyboard
2. https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

Please help.

Comment: _"Dependencies:  jQuery"_ I can't see `jQuery` in your dependencies. You mentioned two errors. Please show an [mcve].

Comment: code blocks added, `jquery.min.js` added for dependency.

Comment: `<script src="../node_modules/ng-virtual-keyboard/src/ng-virtual-keyboard.js"></script>` The source of a script is an URL. That's the reason `ng-virtual-keyboard.js` can't be found. You could add it to your scripts section of angular.json.

Comment: Added `ng-virtual-keyboard.js` in the scripts section of angular.json. Now the only error I have `Cannot find module 'ng-virtual-keyboard'`.

Comment: Isn't this library an AngularJS library? It depends on `"angular": "^1.3.x",`

Comment: This is an angularJS library. You should use the one for angular to start with. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xroussel/ng-virtual-keyboard

Comment: be carefull, it does not support version 8 and above

Answer (score 1):

Install this angular virtual keyboard instead it should support your `Angular` version but not later versions:  [xroussel/ng-virtual-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@xroussel/ng-virtual-keyboard)

**How to install it according to the dokumentation:**

Step 1: `npm install --save @protacon/ng-virtual-keyboard`

Step 2:
Add `NgVirtualKeyboardModule` as an import in your app's root module `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgVirtualKeyboardModule }  from '@protacon/ng-virtual-keyboard';
 

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    NgVirtualKeyboardModule,
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Add this to your `HTML` file and your ready to go:

```
<input type="text" value=""
  ng-virtual-keyboard
  ng-virtual-keyboard-layout="alphanumeric"
  ng-virtual-keyboard-placeholder="test"
  ng-virtual-keyboard-type="password"
/>
```

If that dosen't work you could try `simple-keyboard`, an working Example here with just `HTML` and `Javascript`:

**NOTE:** There is also an way to implement it with `npm` to skip the `<link>` and `<script>` tags here: [simple-keyboard](https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/getting-started/angular/)

```js
const Keyboard = window.SimpleKeyboard.default;

const myKeyboard = new Keyboard({
  onChange: input => onChange(input),
  onKeyPress: button => onKeyPress(button)
});


function onChange(input) {
  document.querySelector(".input").value = input;
  console.log("Input changed", input);
}


function onKeyPress(button) {
  console.log("Button pressed", button);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/css/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <input class="input" placeholder="Tap on the virtual keyboard to start" />
  <div class="simple-keyboard"></div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/simple-keyboard@latest/build/index.js"></script>
  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```